# ZTE android 4.4 mm text and group texting stopped working

Tags: mms

I have a ZTE Android 4.4 and my group messages all of a sudden want differentiate between each person. My mm texts show download and when I hit download it acts like it is going to open but doesn't. All of this was working fine then just changed. Please help.